# How to scale effectively in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I currently have my libgdx game as 720x1280. I totally forgot when making the game that different screen sizes will affect the resolution and how the game looks. All of my rendering is done in pixels so I am wondering if there is a simple way to scale my game so that the game reads it as 720x1280 and then scales it down to the correct size? I really don't know how to change all my values to floats and get it to work the same as before. I heard that veiwports work but I am not sure how those work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels/